# camel cxf soap and karaf issue

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Hi I'm facing this issue -Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]
Offending resource: URL [bundle://2888.0:0/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]
while deploying bundle into karaf.

My code is like below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd               
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring        
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context            
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

<camelContext id="SOAPSERVICE" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <routeBuilder id="soapRouter" ref="soapRoute"/>
</camelContext>
<bean class="com.example.router.SoapRouter" id="soapRoute"/>

 <!-- setting up a Camel CXF web-service -->
 <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="exampleServiceEndPoint"
               address="http://localhost:9000/example/"
                  wsdlURL="http://localhost:9000/example?wsdl"
               serviceClass="com.example.ExampleServiceEndpoint"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install camel-spring feature on your container

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem with Camel > 3.8, add `camel-spring-xml`. Using the spring xml dsl has been [split off](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_9.html#_modularized_camel_spring)